# How can I access the RowKey (and PartitionKey) when I use a input binding with a storage Table?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

How can I access the RowKey (and PartitionKey) when I use a input binding with a storage Table without the error "hides inherited member 'TableEntity.RowKey"?

I can happily access the categories based on a PartitionKey, but when I try to extend to getting the RowKey, by adding a new property to my class, I get an error ... `warning CS0108: 'Person.RowKey' hides inherited member 'TableEntity.RowKey'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.`

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
public static void Run(string myQueueItem, 
                      IQueryable<Person> tableBinding, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger:triggerblocklist processed message : [{myQueueItem}]");
    // int i = tableBinding.Count(); 
    // log.Info($"{i}");

    foreach (Person person in tableBinding.Where(p => p.PartitionKey == myQueueItem)
           .ToList())
    {
        log.Info($"RowKey:     [{person.RowKey}]");
        log.Info($"Categories: [{person.Categories}]");
    }
}
public class Person : TableEntity
{
    // public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Any feedback on why the vote down ? ... it doesn't seem a totally stupid question,Ok so it's a beginners question, but why vote down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TableEntity` class which you inherit from already has a property called `RowKey`, so.. your `Person` class does not need to define a property called `RowKey`, it already has it through its base class.

All you need to do here is to remove `RowKey` property from your `Person` class and no other change is needed.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what you mean, and glad to say it works fine